# How to display Model in each HTML template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

But create a request in each functions inside views.py I do not want.
Is it possible to output the model in each template using only one request?
I tried to use templateetags but
that so

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def header_categories(context):
    return Categorie.objects.all().order_by('id')
```

what is like that

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def header_categories(context):
    categories = Categorie.objects.all().order_by('id')
    args = {}
    
    for cat in categories:
        args[cat.text] = {
        'id':cat.id,
        }
        if cat.parent:
            args[cat.text]['parent_id'] = cat.parent.id
            args[cat.text]['parent_text'] = cat.parent.text
    return args
```

Nothing works correctly

```
{% for cat in header_categories %}
    cat.text
{% endfor %}
```

I tried through js

```
 var arr = {%header_categories%}
```

but django changes everything

```
 {&#x27;dresses&#x27;: {&#x27;id&#x27;: 19},
```

Answer (score 1):

Before going deeper into your question, I think you should have

```
{% for cat in header_categories %}
    {{ cat.text }}  
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a custom context processor (See [Using `RequestContext` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext)). What this would do is add a variable to the context for each template. Quoting the documentation:

> The **context_processors** option is a list of callables – called
> **context processors** – that take a request object as their argument and return a dictionary of items to be merged into the context.

In some suitable app of yours make a file named `context_processors.py` and add this code in it:

```py
def header_categories(request):
    return {'header_categories': Categorie.objects.all().order_by('id')}
```

Now in your settings in the `TEMPLATES` settings add this context processor to the list `context_processors`, so it should look like:

```py
[
    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
    'django.template.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'your_app.context_processors.header_categories',
]
```

Now in your templates you can simply write:

```
{% for cat in header_categories %}
    {{ cat.text }}
{% endfor %}
```